# How to use/integrat the Piwik tracking API in Symfony 2 without JavaScript

Tags: symfony, matomo

I would like to track the users on my Symfony 2.7 page using Piwik.

Piwiks default tracking option is the integration of a small JavaScript into the webpage, e.g. with the page footer. Of course this could easily be done by adding the code to the base `Twig` template.

However I would like to avoid the usage of JavaScript. My Symfony page and the Piwik page both run on the same server. Actually I am surprised that letting the client communicate with Piwik (over Javascript) is the recommended option instead of a *direct* way to let the webpage server talk to Piwik.

**I think the [`Tracking HTTP API`](http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-api) and the [`PHP Client`](http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/PHP-Piwik-Tracker) are what I am looking for. However I am not sure on how to integrate this into Symfony.**

I managed to connect my Symfony page with Piwik, however I wonder if this the right/best way to do it:

- Used `composer require "piwik/piwik-php-tracker"` to add the `PHPTracker` to my Symfony project
- Added a new `Service` that is responsible to create and manage a `PiwikTracker` object. The Service makes different methods of the Tracker, e.g. `doTrackPageView()` available to the rest of the project.
- Added a new `Twig` function which uses the Service to trigger the `doTrackPageView()` method.
- Added a call to this function to my base template

**This works fine:** Page views are correctly reported to Piwik and recorded without any problem. Of course I could easily add other methods to track events, actions, etc.

**But:** I am really surprised that I could not find any ready-to-use solution for this. Did I miss anything or is this the indented way to use Piwik with Symfony?

Comment: You can always prepare ready-to-use solution and provide it to the community. It doesn;t have to be perfect. You can connect Symfony with PHPClient any way you want as long as it is consistent with Symfony philosophy. PHPClient is just an alternative to JS Tracking. So I think you didn't miss anything.